# Wordpress - Delayed loading of main rollover buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I converted a website into WordPress off of an HTML/CSS website we created a while ago. I created the roll over buttons in the header so a blue, rounded background would appear when a user hovers over them. It works perfectly on every browser except Google Chrome.

In Chrome it appears when you hover over it (minus the left rounded side) and then the far left side of the blue background swipes down slowly until it is the image I want.

Below is a screenshot of the menu buttons I have so far and the look at how the delayed loading of the background looks. The "Home" Button is how the blue background should flash in as. (Simple appear effect nothing too fancy) and the "Remote Monitoring" button is where I caught the loading issue with a well timed screenshot.

(Here is the screenshot: s23.postimg.org/cwkbs5wsr/wploadingissue.png)

I have tried a bunch of different fixes and nothing seems to be working, again this is only an issue on the Google Chrome browser not IE or Firefox when I checked those.

Any ideas for troubleshooting this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you some code of how this works and what have you tried so far. I can't really quite get what exactly you want it to be.

Comment: Yes we need code examples to help.

Looks like an element with white background is underneath?